# How to use a jar file in javase native interface cn1

Tags: codenameone

I cannot seem to find a way to implement a jar file. I have made a javase native interface  tried placing a jar file in the native/javase directory as well as placing a cn1Lib file with the jar file in the project's lib directory. I receive an error that the package does not exist. 
error:

```
ant -f C:\\Users\\Robin\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\CnoGUIPrac -Dnb.internal.action.name=rebuild clean jar
No GUI Entries available
init:
deps-clean:
Updating property file: C:\Users\Robin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CnoGUIPrac\build\built-clean.properties
Deleting directory C:\Users\Robin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CnoGUIPrac\build
refresh-libs:
Deleting directory C:\Users\Robin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CnoGUIPrac\lib\impl
clean:
No GUI Entries available
init:
deps-jar:
Created dir: C:\Users\Robin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CnoGUIPrac\build
Updating property file: C:\Users\Robin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CnoGUIPrac\build\built-jar.properties
Created dir: C:\Users\Robin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CnoGUIPrac\build\classes
Compile is forcing compliance to the supported API's/features for maximum device compatibility. This allows smaller
        code size and wider device support
Created dir: C:\Users\Robin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CnoGUIPrac\build\tmp
Compiling 4 source files to C:\Users\Robin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CnoGUIPrac\build\tmp
Created dir: C:\Users\Robin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CnoGUIPrac\build\empty
Created dir: C:\Users\Robin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CnoGUIPrac\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output
Compiling 4 source files to C:\Users\Robin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CnoGUIPrac\build\classes
Copying 3 files to C:\Users\Robin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CnoGUIPrac\build\classes
compile:
Created dir: C:\Users\Robin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CnoGUIPrac\dist
Copying 1 file to C:\Users\Robin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CnoGUIPrac\build
Not copying library C:\Users\Robin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CnoGUIPrac\override , it's a directory.
Not copying library C:\Users\Robin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CnoGUIPrac\lib\impl\cls , it's a directory.
Not copying library C:\Users\Robin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CnoGUIPrac\lib\impl\stubs , it's a directory.
Not copying library C:\Users\Robin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CnoGUIPrac\native\internal_tmp , it's a directory.
Copy libraries to C:\Users\Robin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CnoGUIPrac\dist\lib.
Building jar: C:\Users\Robin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CnoGUIPrac\dist\CnoGUIPrac.jar
To run this application from the command line without Ant, try:
java -jar "C:\Users\Robin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CnoGUIPrac\dist\CnoGUIPrac.jar"
Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\Robin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CnoGUIPrac\native\internal_tmp
C:\Users\Robin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CnoGUIPrac\native\javase\com\mycompany\myapp\MyNativeImpl.java:7: error: package main does not exist
import main.UserDB;
C:\Users\Robin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CnoGUIPrac\native\javase\com\mycompany\myapp\MyNativeImpl.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
        UserDB u = new UserDB();
  symbol:   class UserDB
  location: class MyNativeImpl
C:\Users\Robin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CnoGUIPrac\native\javase\com\mycompany\myapp\MyNativeImpl.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
        UserDB u = new UserDB();
  symbol:   class UserDB
  location: class MyNativeImpl
3 errors
C:\Users\Robin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CnoGUIPrac\build.xml:434: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 3 seconds)
```

Comment: Don't mix both cn1libs and native interfaces in your code. Pick one and go with that. Please include the actual error message you are getting, notice that IDE code completion might not work correctly. We also need to know which IDE you are using.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am using netbeans 8.1. My aim is to import and use a package from a Java Application project. I can import the package but when I build the cn1 project it just says the package does not exist.

Comment: I need the exact error message (full output from the console) notice that the import statement highlighting might not work as the IDE doesn't "see" the jar.

Comment: Okay thank you. I have added the error message.

Comment: What's the version of your plugin? The build XML seems to be out of date it's also missing portions at the top. Can you please paste the full error log and please try to format it as code or as a quote so it will be more readable. Thanks.

Comment: I have now updated it to the latest version. It still seems to have the same error though.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear about the build.xml version. Update the plugin to the latest version then right click the project and select `Codename One -> Codename One Settings`. Then click the save button on the top right, it should offer to update the `build.xml` file that is out of date. You should say yes. This might still fail the build but then the line numbers pointing into the `build.xml` will match my line numbers which will help me track the issue so even if it fails please update the messages above. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at this a bit further I think my recollection is a bit hazy, you need to add the jar file manually to the project.

Right click the project and select `Properties`. In there select `Libraries` and then click `Add Jar` to add your JAR to the classpath.